# Using fourier expansion to find the constant

Tags: fourier-series

I have the expression $$1=\sum^\infty_{n=1} c_n \left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right) \cosh \left(\frac{2 \pi n y}{3}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi n y}{3}\right)$$

I am trying to find the constant $$c_n$$

The first thing I did was to multiply both sides by $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi m y}{3}\right)$$
 I also let $$m=n$$
This gave me $$sin\left(\frac{\pi n y}{3}\right)=\sum^\infty_{n=1} c_n \left(\frac{\pi n}{3}\right) \cosh\left(\frac{2 \pi n y}{3}\right) \sin^2 \left(\frac{\pi n y}{3}\right)$$

I look at the RHS: $$\int^3_0 \left(\frac{\pi n }{3}\right) c_n \cosh \left(\frac{2 \pi n y}{3}\right) \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi n y}{3}\right)dy$$

I solve this then make the answer equal to $$\int^3_0 \sin\left(\frac{\pi n y}{3}\right) dy$$ and then solve for $$c_n$$

I followed this method but I got a completely wrong answer and I am not sure where?

Comment: How did you arrive at the mentioned integral ?

Comment: You should backslash your trig functions

Comment: @ echan I thought it was the standard way for orthogonality? The m does become an n because I set m=n

Comment: It looks like your problem is that $\sin(\pi m y/3)$ is not orthogonal to $\cosh(2\pi ny/3) \sin(\pi n y/3)$ when $m\neq n$.

Comment: @echan so what do I do then?

Comment: If you put y = 0, you get 1 = 0.  So the equation can not be true.